# The most convenient way to get videos related with a specific topic using Youtube Data API

Tags: android, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube Data API to get videos regarding some specific games. As you might know that using `search.list` costs 100 units and I think, it consumes lots of your quota.

Is there a way to do this using `videos.list` which costs only 5 units. Maybe there is some kind of filtration but I couldn't find out by myself.

For instance this is the link for GTA5 game under Youtube Gaming.

https://gaming.youtube.com/game/**UCT1tnevF8bn9Nwr6ZHA9Mag**

what is that bold part in the link? Is it something like gameID or something like that? Could it be useful to get videos using Youtube Data API?

My goal is getting these videos with low unit cost. I am open to any kind of ideas. The language is not really important but I am using Java.

Comment: Why so worried over 100 units? You get a MILLION units to use free each day. (50 MILLION if your key was made before April)

Comment: I am creating a background service that uses the API frequently. If I have more than 500 daily users, the app becomes unusable. If I could decrease the cost to 5, this number of users could go up to 10000 which I can't have. I already started to use search.list unfortunately. Do you have any idea about API pricing @johnh10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query a video regarding a specific topic, then I think only the `search.list` can give you the access with it. Because [`search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) has the only one that has a parameter **topicId** that indicates that the API response should only contain resources associated with the specified topic. If you check the [`playlist.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) and [`video.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#top_of_page) they don't have that specific parameter

Comment: do you know where can i find the Topics Ids  ?? to set it as a parameter for the query ??